# How can I access the properties of a nested object in Angular?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object, nested

I have this Model-class.

```
export class Drivefunction{
public Injection: Injection;
public df_uid_machine_injsiz:string;
public Motor_Cable_IEC: Motor_cable;
...
```

And in my display.component.ts I have this function which fills my Drivefunction[]

```
fillDrivefunctions(){
  this.machineService.getDrivefunctions(this.injectionID)
    .subscribe((df:Drivefunction[])=> {
      this.drivefunctions = df;
      console.log(this.drivefunctions)
    });
}
```

As you see I try a console.log to see if the json Objects a properly filled

[image]

all Objects and nested Objects are filled!

and in my HTML I have a ngFor with my drivefunction[]
I can access properties like strings but get "cannot read property of undefined" if i try to access an nested object even if it's correctly filled.

**Do I have to "extra" subscribe this nested objects?**

my HTML:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let drivefunction of this.drivefunctions; ">
    <ion-item> 
       <ion-label>{{drivefunction.Injection.inj_uid_machine_injsiz}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: add the HTML to the question

Comment: @RameshReddy done

Comment: `{{drivefunction.Injection?.inj_uid_machine_injsiz}}` use the `?` operator. If Injection isn't populated it won't try to access inj_uid_machine_injsiz. you also don't need the `this` in the html.

Comment: @rhavelka i know but my nested objects are undefined, but as you see the console output they aren't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a typo problem.

Based on the HTML you gave.

```html
<ion-label>{{drivefunction.Injection.inj_uid_machine_injsiz}}</ion-label>
```

Bu in the console screenshot, we can see that `Injection` is lowercase. Try

```html
<ion-label>{{drivefunction.injection.inj_uid_machine_injsiz}}</ion-label>
```

And change the `Drivefunction` class accordingly:

```
export class Drivefunction {
   public injection: Injection;
...
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I didn't see it. +1 for you

Comment: @futuremanuel I have added details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to declare your `drivefunction` properties as an `array`. It will looks like this code below:

```js
public drivefunction: Array<Drivefunction> = new Array();
```

So now, you will get te result. I hope so.

Comment: leaving the variable undeclared wouldn't cause the "cannot read property of undefined" error

Comment: I thinks it will, if you don't use *ngIf condition and you use the loop. Baceuse you can loop undefined value of a property, when the data still waiting for response.

Comment: It doesn't, if the array is `[]`, `null`, or `undefined` then there is nothing to loop over, so the *ngFor doesn't try to access any of the child objects. you can play around in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egaswg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination.